# Place Order Magento 2.1 REST API as a guest for Android app

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, android

I want to place order on Magento 2.1 using REST API, Please provide me all steps from creating cart to Place order, Actually i need parameters to pass for guest, How i'll set Customer_id etc for guest? Because i am guest how i can have customer id?

Answer (score 0):

First -

POST : `/rest/V1/guest-carts`

Use the response from this for the following steps.

Second, put an item in the cart using the repsonse -

POST `/rest/V1/carts/CARTID/items`

```
{
"cart_item": {
"quote_id": QUOTE ID FROM LAST STEP,
"sku": "TEST",
"qty": 1
}
}
```

Next, add billing / shipping -

POST `/rest/V1/carts/CARTID/billing-address`

```
{
"address": {
"city": "",
"country_id": "",
"company": "",
"email": "",
"firstname": "",
"lastname": "",
"postcode": "",
"region": "",
"saveInAddressBook": ,
"street": [""],
"telephone": ""
},
"useForShipping": 
}
```

POST `/rest/V1/carts/CARTID/shipping-information`

```
{
"addressInformation": {
"shippingAddress": {
"region": "",
"region_id": 0,
"country_id": "",
"street": [
""
],
"company": "",
"telephone": "",
"postcode": "",
"city": "",
"firstname": "",
"lastname": "",
"email": "",
"prefix": "",
"region_code": "",
"sameAsBilling": 
},
"shipping_method_code": "flatrate",
"shipping_carrier_code": "flatrate"
}
}
```

Lastly

PUT `/rest/V1/carts/CARTID/order`

```
{
"paymentMethod": {
"method": "checkmo"
}
}
```

More information can be found in the [swagger documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html). Try looking at the "**quoteGuestCartItemRepository**", "**quoteGuestCartManagementV1**".